# PHP: Get a part from a path

Tags: php, dirname

I got a string, which gives me the location of something:

`/var/www/web1/htdocs`
The problem is: The last part could possibly change: It could also be `/var/www/web1/public_html` or `/var/www/web1/httpdocs`.

Now I would like to get the path without the last part of the path:

`/var/www/web1`

How can I do that?

Comment: Use this `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`

Comment: Hi and thank you for your answer.No, that does not work, because the path has nothing to do with the script itself. It's provided by the user.

They could also give `/home/mydir` which should result in `/home/`

Comment: so you're going to get that string as input?? If so then you can explode it with `/`. And depending on the length of exploded array you can reform the path with -1 value

Answer (score 1):

As far as i understand your question, you need something like this

```
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; //your URL or PATH ENTERED BY USER.
$parts = explode('/',$url);
print_r($parts);
```

Answer (score 0):

.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
#RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

insert code file index.php

```
echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],"<br>",$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'],"<br>",$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'],'<br>',$_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"],"<br>",$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
```